# Invoking a list of methods with correct arguments in Python

Tags: python, method-chaining

I'm trying to execute a list of functions with the output of some functions being used as inputs to other ones.

A simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
def a():
    return 25

def b():
    return 50

def c(x, y):
    return x+y
```

Normally, I'd do: `print c(a(), b())`

But if I have a list of functions: `l = [a,b,c]`

How can I iterate over this list and get the right arguments passed into method c?

Thanks.

Comment: `l[2](l[0](), l[1]())`

Comment: are the functions in the list guaranteed to be in that order?

Comment: Your probably gonna need to include additional examples as well as a bit more information about how you intend to use it.

Comment: pass the funcs as keywords args `def c(x=a(), y=b()):`

Comment: Do the lists of functions change size? Is it always the last function that gets called with the results of the functions leading up to it?

Comment: Yes, the functions will be in order. A function that depends on another function will be later in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My previous answer was not generic enough, so here's another bash at it. This uses `inspect.getargspec()` to determine the arity of each function prior to calling it. With that knowledge the required number of arguments can be sliced out of a "results list" which contains the results of all previous function calls.

There are some limitations:

- `inspect.getargspec()` doesn't work for built-in functions, only user defined ones.
- varargs and keyword args are ignored because this results in possibly infinite arguments which just complicates things.

Code:

```
import inspect

def a():
    return 25

def b():
    return 50

def c(x, y):
    return x + y

def d(x, y, z):
    return x + y + z

def e(x=100):
    return x * x

def f():
    pass


def execute_function_list(funcs):
    results = []
    for i, fn in enumerate(funcs):
        args_required = len(inspect.getargspec(fn).args)
        if args_required > 0:
            args = results[i-args_required:i]
        else:
            args = ()
        print("calling function %r with args %r" % (fn, args))
        results.append(fn(*args))
        print("after function returned results = %r" % results)
    return results[-1] if len(results) else None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    funcs = [e, a, b, c, d, e]
    print("final result is %r" % execute_function_list(funcs))
```

Comment: This is the closest to what I'm trying to do and put me on the right track. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the last function in the list is to be called with the results of all of the preceding functions in the list:

```
def c(*args):
    "Return the sum of all function arguments"
    return sum(args)

>>> l = [a, b, a, b, b, b, c]
>>> args=(f() for f in l[:-1])
>>> args
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fd441aabe60>
>>> l[-1](*args)
250
```

or in one line,

```
>>> l[-1](*(f() for f in l[:-1]))
250
```

Comment: Thank you. While this works for the example in my question, what I have is a more generic list of functions that I need to execute in order. Some of these functions accept arguments whose values are returned by one or more previous functions. So I need to keep track of the value returned by the first method, for instance, and pass it into the 2nd and 3rd one, the output of method 3 goes into method 4 etc.

Comment: In that case, what would be done with the output of the 2nd method? Would it not have an output (returns None) in that example? If the latter is the case, then it seems like a recursive helper method would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the built-in function `apply`:

`apply( l[-1], [ func() for func in l[:-1] ] )`

Comment: This doesn't work, besides, `apply` has been deprecated since 2.3. This will do it though: `apply( l[-1], [f() for f in l[:-1]] )`